# How I can write this equation in LaTeX

Tags: math-mode

[image]

I’m still a beginner to LaTeX, and I don’t know how to write this equation.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Did you read an introduction to LaTeX? Please show us what you have tried so far ...

Comment: Isn't this the same question you asked a day ago? Please advise if this impression is incorrect.

Comment: To write equations simply the easiest way is to use LyX because it allows you to view the rendering live. Watch this very short video: [How to use mathematical formula editor in LYX - LaTeX](https://youtu.be/uBCwK4vUkic) Home page of Lyx [LyX – The Document Processor](https://www.lyx.org)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
  \mathrm{ASD}(P_{\text{ref}}, P_{\text{auto}}) = 
    \frac{1}{\lvert P_{\text{ref}} \rvert}
    \sum_{p \in P_{\text{ref}}} d(p, P_{\text{auto}})
\]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

<sup>This is an expanded version of @Werner's answer.</sup>

---

Welcome to TeX.SE!

I can see that you are in a great hurry, so I decide to post an answer here (in additional with an upvote). However, you just have to spend about 15 minutes reading and practicing to get what you want.

---

This is your equation:

```
\text{ASD}(P_\text{ref},P_\text{auto})=\frac{1}{\vert P_\text{ref}\vert}\sum_{p\in P_\text{ref}}d(p,P_\text{auto}),
```

[image]

This is another equation (which you posted yesterday -- I'm sorry if I remember it wrong:

```
\text{MSD}(P_\text{ref},P_\text{auto})=\max\left\{\max_{q\in P_\text{ref}}d(q,P_\text{auto}),\max_{q\in P_\text{auto}}d(q,P_\text{ref})\right\},
```

[image]

---

In a bit more advanced level (it is still basic) you should define your own `\pref` and `\pauto` to avoid using too many `P_\text{ref}` and `P_\text{auto}`. This is a complete code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\pref}{P_\text{ref}}
\newcommand{\pauto}{P_\text{auto}}
\begin{document}
\[
    \text{ASD}(\pref,\pauto)=\frac{1}{\vert\pref\vert}\sum_{p\in\pref}d(p,\pauto),
\]
And
\[
    \text{MSD}(\pref,\pauto)=\max\left\{\max_{q\in\pref}d(q,\pauto),\max_{q\in\pauto}d(q,\pref)\right\},
\]
\end{document}
```